# How do I get this navigation to work on iphone and ipad, though it is responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am not sure what is the standard bootstrap way to get this nav working in ipad and iphone. if I shrink the pages the horizontal scroll appears and I think that is not a desired effect.

```
<div id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-static span8" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<!-- navigation -->
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Animal Types</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mammals <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="chimpanzee">Chimpanzee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="lemur">Lemur</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="jaguar">Jaguar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reptiles <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="cobra">Cobra</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="eidechse">Eidechse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="iguana">Iguana</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rodents <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="chipmunk">Chipmunk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="beaver">Beaver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="hamster">Hamster</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- content pages -->
```

Live Example is here:

http://tonysilvestri.com/examples/twitterBootstrapDropdown/bootstrapDropdownExample.html#

Bottom Line:

How do we develop a sub level menu pages for iphones/ipads  using twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Are you including the media queries that are optional in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

To implement a collapsing responsive navbar, wrap your navbar content in a containing div, `.nav-collapse.collapse`, and add the navbar toggle button, `.btn-navbar`.

Try this

```
<div id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-static span8" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<!-- navigation -->
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Animal Types</a>

 <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>        

 <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mammals <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="chimpanzee">Chimpanzee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="lemur">Lemur</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="jaguar">Jaguar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reptiles <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="cobra">Cobra</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="eidechse">Eidechse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="iguana">Iguana</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rodents <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="chipmunk">Chipmunk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="beaver">Beaver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false" id="hamster">Hamster</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>        



    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I get the word Mammals to open  a new link on click and on hover the sub menu should open

Comment: add this style for hover : ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;    
}

Comment: use this jquery for open new link : $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).attr('href');
  });